# Java, hibernate, h2db and mysql date and time variable

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date, orm

I'am on decision: "Which format/type of variable I should use to store/work on/convert/ dates in my Java/Spring or PlayFramework app.

The most common date format use in my app will be: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. f.e. 2014-07-17 15:06:00

Example usage of date is: creation datetime, update datetime, last visited datetime
The date will be store in database using hibernate or native sql query.

I will be working on date objects (f.e. adding dayes, months, sec or houres)

Please give me some advice, what should I use in Your opinion (maybe some good article)

I am thinking about:

- unix timestamp as long or int variable
- java.util.date object
- java.sql.timestamp object
- java.util.calendar object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide to use Joda Time. The best java date and time library!